# Custom App Icon Not Showing in .NET MAUI App on Android After Migration from Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, migration, maui, appicon

I recently migrated my app/game from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI and encountered an issue where the custom app icon is not displayed on Android devices.
I work with Visual Studio 2022 (version 17.9.3).
Instead of showing the specified icon, it defaults to the standard Android icon. Interestingly, when I launch the Windows version of the app, the custom icon displays correctly.

Tested on emulator for Pixel 5 and physical Pixel 7 Pro.
Tried both SVG and PNG formats for the icon, ensuring they're placed in the Resources/AppIcon directory with the MauiIcon build action.
Put MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" (or  png) correctly in the csproj
Performed clean and rebuild operations on the project multiple times.
Additionally, the splash screen also does not appear on Android

Comment: Did you used the [Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/upgrade-assistant?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vswin)? In addition, could you please show the csproj?

Comment: I manually migrated my project from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI. Below is the configuration section from my .csproj file related to the app icon and splash screen:

     <ItemGroup>
      <!-- App Icon -->
      <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" />
  

      <!-- Splash Screen -->
      <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Images\splash.png" Color="#3498db" 
     BaseSize="251,480" />
    </ItemGroup>


This configuration specifies an SVG file for the app icon and a PNG file for the splash screen, along with a background color and base size for the splash screen.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. DId this problem appear if you upgrade a new xamarin forms project?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. 
The problem appear after upgrade the project to Maui , <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" /> i can't get it work. 
For now i made another solution by putting back the mipmaps in the android platform and edit de androidmanifest.

Comment: Yes, that's also a solution. But the problem is still strange. Maybe you can rename the custom icon'f file name to make if different from the default icon's name(appicon.svg). And then clean and rebuild it.